# How to get the remove button to work on this piece of code

Tags: javascript, dom

This is an exercise from a test.

I need to get the remove button working. I don't understand why the line

```
document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
```

is there either

Here is the code

```
function setup() {
  // Write your code here.
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div class="image">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>`;

setup();

document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Edit: The expected output is that the remove button would remove the parent div (class="image")

Comment: Your question is unclear and seems you didn't tried anything. What is your expected output?

Comment: @MaheerAli I edited the question to add the expected output, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the "remove' button doesn't have a callback function for the `click` event defined for it.

Also, this: `document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0]` should not be used as it causes a live node list to be created only to throw away that node list for just the first item in it. Instead, `document.querySelector(".remove")` should be used. See this [other post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) for details on this.

So, if we add a `click` event handler and clean up your code it will work:

```js
function setup() {
  // Write your code here.
  
  // This will set up a callback function for when the remove button gets clicked:
  theRemoveButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("You clicked the remove button!");
    this.closest(".image").remove();
  });
}

// Example case. 
document.body.innerHTML = `
<div class="image">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="First">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="Second">
  <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>`;

var theRemoveButton = document.querySelector(".remove");

setup();

theRemoveButton.click();  // Forces the click event to fire on the button
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0] was in the test. I was wondering why they put that there, as it seems not to make any sense

Is there a way to solve this writing code only where it says "Write you code"

Comment: @user3808307 Unfortunately, most teachers and courses on HTML, CSS and JavaScript are taught/written by people who don't really know and understand these languages.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your problem but the

```
document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].click();
```

line simulate a click on the first element of the with a css class called "remove", so it's useless because no event are attached to this element.
I think the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function is what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That part was in the test, as a prewritten code. So it's strange